# Using Keys to move object and shooting mini squares

Tags: processing

In my key pressed section, I'm not too sure what I need to do in order for the square to move up and down. It is currently very slow. I also am trying to figure out how Mini square would be shot from the big square;

```
boolean updown = false;
int squareX = 20;
int squareY = 20;
int speed = 30;
int circleX = 150;

void setup () {
  size (700,700);
}

void draw () {
  background (0);

  fill(100);
  ellipse (circleX,140,150,150);
  circleX -=2;
  if (circleX < - 20) {
    circleX = 550;
  }

  fill (225);
  rect (squareX, squareY, 70, 70);
  if (updown) squareY = squareY + speed;
  
   if (squareY>width || squareY <0) {
     speed=speed*-1;

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you're directly incrementing `squareY` by 1 pixel.
Ideally you'd simply control velocity by setting it to a value > 0 when you want to move the square or reset it back to 0 when you want the movement to stop.

There are a couple of other things that could make this nicer, such as:

- using the size of the square when checking if the square is outside the screen area or not
- remembering the last good y position before the square went offscreen to reset the position to when flipping the position.

Here's a modified version of your sketch with the above notes as well as naming variables in way the keeps related elements grouped:

```
int squarePositionX = 20;
int squarePositionY = 20;
int squareVelocityY = 0;
int squareLastGoodY = squarePositionY;
int squareSize = 70;
int squareSpeed = 9;

int circleX = 150;

void setup () {
  size (700, 700);
}

void draw () {
  // handle keys
  if(keyPressed){
    if(key == 'w'){
      squareVelocityY = -squareSpeed;
    }
    if(key == 's'){
      squareVelocityY =  squareSpeed;
    }
  }else{
    // reset velocity (stop square from moving)
    squareVelocityY = 0;
  }
  
  // update big square position based on velocity
  squarePositionY += squareVelocityY;
  // check if square is still on screen (reset velocity if it's not otherwise keep track of it's last 
  if (squarePositionY >= width - squareSize || squarePositionY <= 0) {
    // flip Y velocity
    squareVelocityY *= -1;
    // reset to last good known Y position
    squarePositionY = squareLastGoodY;
  }else{
    squareLastGoodY = squarePositionY;
  }
  
  // clear screen
  background (0);

  // render big square
  fill (225);
  rect (squarePositionX, squarePositionY, squareSize, squareSize);
  
  // render circle
  fill(100);
  ellipse (circleX, 140, 150, 150);
  // update circle position
  circleX -= 2;
  if (circleX < - 20) {
    circleX = 550;
  }
}
```

Hopefully the comments help explain in more detail what's going on.

Regarding shooting mini squares you'd need to keep track of the positions of each mini square. You could use an array and [`append()`](https://processing.org/reference/append_.html) to expand it as new bullets are shot, or just go for an array type with dynamic size such as [`ArrayList`](https://processing.org/reference/ArrayList.html) or [`IntList`](https://processing.org/reference/IntList_set_.html). To keep the list efficient and not flood it with bullets that are outside of the screen area you could do a similar test to the large square to check when the small squares are offscreen remove from the list. The last thing left to do is simply rendering the small squares as long as long as they are visible.

Here's a commented sketch to illustrate the idea:

```
int squareSize = 70;
int squarePositionX = squareSize;
int squarePositionY = squareSize;
int squareVelocityY = 0;
int squareLastGoodY = squarePositionY;
int squareSpeed = 3;

int circleX = 150;

// store positions for 
IntList miniSquarePositionsX = new IntList();
IntList miniSquarePositionsY = new IntList();
int miniSquareSpeed = 9;
int miniSquareSize  = 35;

void setup () {
  size (700, 700);
  rectMode(CENTER);
}

void draw () {
  // handle keys
  if(keyPressed){
    if(key == 'w' && key != ' '){
      squareVelocityY = -squareSpeed;
    }else
    if(key == 's' && key != ' '){
      squareVelocityY =  squareSpeed;
    }
  }else{
    // reset velocity (stop square from moving)
    squareVelocityY = 0;
  }
  
  // update big square position based on velocity
  squarePositionY += squareVelocityY;
  // check if square is still on screen (reset velocity if it's not otherwise keep track of it's last 
  if (squarePositionY >= width - (squareSize * 0.5) || squarePositionY <= (squareSize * 0.5)) {
    // flip Y velocity
    squareVelocityY *= -1;
    // reset to last good known Y position
    squarePositionY = squareLastGoodY;
  }else{
    squareLastGoodY = squarePositionY;
  }
  
  // update mini squares: assumes the size of both x and y lists match
  for(int i = 0 ; i < miniSquarePositionsX.size(); i++){
    // update X position
    miniSquarePositionsX.set(i, miniSquarePositionsX.get(i) + miniSquareSpeed);
    // remove element if it's outside the screen
    if(miniSquarePositionsX.get(i) > width){
      miniSquarePositionsX.remove(i);
      miniSquarePositionsY.remove(i);
    }
  }
  // clear screen
  background (0);

  // render circle
  fill(100);
  ellipse (circleX, 140, 150, 150);
  
  // render big square
  fill (225);
  rect (squarePositionX, squarePositionY, squareSize, squareSize);
  
  // update circle position
  circleX -= 2;
  if (circleX < - 20) {
    circleX = 550;
  }
  // render mini squares: assumes the size of both x and y lists match
  for(int i = 0 ; i < miniSquarePositionsX.size(); i++){
    rect(miniSquarePositionsX.get(i), miniSquarePositionsY.get(i), miniSquareSize, miniSquareSize);
  }
}

void keyReleased(){
  // SPACE key shoot
  if(key == ' '){
    // add position entries for a mini square
    miniSquarePositionsX.append(squarePositionX);
    miniSquarePositionsY.append(squarePositionY);
    println(miniSquarePositionsY);
  }
}
```

If you're familiar with Object Oriented Programming (OOP) basics the above can be nicely encapsulated using a couple of classes (such as a Square class for the "ship" and a `MiniSquare` class for the "bullets"). Have fun!